# Toggle button when objects are shown or hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image on the body and then above the image I have a big box, footer, nav and header.

I am trying to implement a button which is linked to a class called slideUp. This class has an image of an arrow pointing upwards.

When I click on this button the box, footer, nav and header will slide up and disappear. Then I have another button with another class called slideDown where I have an image of an arrow pointng downwards. When I click on this button everything will slide back down.

Instead of both buttons showing at all time I want to use a if statement, when everything is visible, show buttonUp, hide buttonDown and when everything is hidden, show buttonDown and hide buttonUp.

The first part works fine, it shows buttonUp and hides ButtonDown but the the 'else if' doesn't work. After I have clicked the buttonUp it does not hide and the buttonDown does not show. I'm using jQuery for the slideUp and slideDown features.

```js
$("button#Up").click(function() {
 $(".box").slideUp("medium");
 $("nav").slideUp("medium");
 $("header").slideUp("medium");
 $("footer").slideUp("medium");
});

$("button#Down").click(function() {
 $(".box").slideDown("medium");
 $("nav").slideDown("medium");
 $("header").slideDown("medium");
 $("footer").slideDown("medium");
});

if ($(".box").is(":visible") && $("nav").is(":visible") && $("header").is(":visible") && $("footer").is(":visible"))
{
  $("button#Up").show("fast");
 $("button#Down").hide("fast");
}
else if ($(".box").is(":hidden") && $("nav").is(":hidden") && $("header").is(":hidden") && $("footer").is(":hidden"))
{
 $("button#Up").hide("fast");
 $("button#Down").show("fast");
}
```

```css
button.slideUp{
 background-image: url(arrowUp.png);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-color: #1A1A1A;
 opacity: 0.75;
 height: 41px;
 width: 41px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 2px;
 bottom: 0px;
}

button.slideDown{
 background-image: url(arrowDown.png);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-color: #1A1A1A;
 opacity: 0.75;
 height: 41px;
 width: 41px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 2px;
 top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<button id="Up" class="slideUp"></button>
<button id="Down" class="slideDown"></button>
```

Comment: provide the html full code

Comment: Make the snippet work like you think it should, meaning add header and footer etc so we can see what's happening, or not happening

Comment: Please add actual content - images from lorempixel or similar to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
$("button#Up").click(function() {
 $(".box").slideUp("medium");
 $("nav").slideUp("medium");
 $("header").slideUp("medium");
 $("footer").slideUp("medium");
 $("button#Down").show();
 $(this).hide();
});

$("button#Down").click(function() {
 $(".box").slideDown("medium");
 $("nav").slideDown("medium");
 $("header").slideDown("medium");
 $("footer").slideDown("medium");
 $("button#Up").show();
 $(this).hide();
});
```

It can all be implemented with one button, toggleClass and toggleSlide

```
$("button").on("click",function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("slideUp slideDown");
 $(".box").toggleSlide("medium");
 $("nav").toggleSlide("medium");
 $("header").toggleSlide("medium");
 $("footer").toggleSlide("medium");
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Though is there a way to use a if statement? Just curious.

Comment: Not outside an event handler. You need to add the if inside where the visibility changes